# Generate spikes on RS485 bus

Tags: rs485, test-equipment, spike

I was thinking to build some test equipment for a RS485 bus, but Would like to get some suggestions on how I can introduce bursts of spikes in a "safe" way without damaging the connected equipment. Maybe even introduce DC offsets or AC ripples.

I only need some suggestion on how to "drive" the bus to introduce this in a safe way, the actual generation of bursts, offsets or AC will be done by a microcontroller.

**EDIT**
On request I will elaborate a bit more.

During software stress test (loading the bus with data traffic), I would like to introduce burst of noise or in other ways "invalidate" the signal on an electrical level to simulate, for example noise introduced when a motor start, or hum from an AC line. Our customers don't always install things the proper way and we get all kind of wierd behaviour because of this. Behaviours we can't repeat in a controlled environment (in our lab).

I know RS485 is a balanced line so it should be a lot more tollerant, but still, there are issues.

The Idea is to connect this test-device on an installation and start to disturb the signal.

Things I could think of would be to hold one (or both) of the balanced lines high or low, regardless of the driver's output. I guess the drivers can handle the case if more than one driver accidently drives in the opposite direction, without breaking. I can have a microcontroller to control when and how to do this and in this way create "bursts" and inject pulses in the middle of the traffic.

This isn't to test the hardware, more to test the software and error handling.

So I would like to get some suggestions on how to hold the bus lines high or low in a "safe" way while the RS485 driver is sending.

I hope this made it more clear now.

Comment: You probably should carefully read the specifications for RS-485 and then equally carefully define the kinds of tests that are most important for the situations you expect are more likely. From that, you can define specific tests and from those crafted definitions others here can then perhaps help you think through an implementation. I doubt there is a generic "RS-485 injector" device with all manner of pre-built tests, at least not an afforable one, as they'd only sell a few and besides that they'd know nothing about what situations you want to test, anyway. Might be a document, though?

Comment: What is the purpose of injecting safe spikes? Calling them spikes makes it sound like you want to stress test the equipment which by definition is not safe so please elaborate your objective. Are you just wanting to test noise immunity?

Comment: Are you looking for an ESD gun? What voltage levels are you wanting to introduce?

Comment: I thought the point of injecting spikes was to see whether the connected equipment gets damaged?

Comment: Could you build a device that is like a reverse current sense transformer and route your RS-485 (either both for common mode stuff or just one for differential stuff) and induce something onto the line? Basically an hollow air-coil winding that you run current through to induce a signal onto the lines running through the core. Wouldn't work for DC offset though. You'd have to actually tape into the cables for that I think.